# Google cloud build unable to fetch private go modules

Tags: git, go, google-cloud-platform, go-modules

I am having some troubles with private modules in a gcloud build. I generated a new ssh key-pair, stored the private key in my gcp projects `secretManager` and the public one in the github repos `Deploy key` . I followed this tutorial without problems: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-private-github-repos

In a build step I am able to clone my repo (which I guess shows that I have a valid connection). But when I try to go get a private repo (private-repo) I get the following:

```
Step #2: go: github.com/felix/private-repo@<version-nr>: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/e61704280b96667bd155fe2e6c284d9506853b470d6786a1dff7011776527149: exit status 128:
Step #2:    ERROR: Repository not found.
Step #2:    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Step #2:    
Step #2:    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
Step #2:    and the repository exists.
Finished Step #2
```

My cloudbuild yaml file:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    secretEnv: ['SSH_KEY']
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
    - -c
    - |
        echo "$$SSH_KEY" >> /root/.ssh/id_rsa
        chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
        git config --global url."git@github.com:myOrg".insteadOf https://github.com/myOrg
    volumes:
    - name: 'ssh'
      path: /root/.ssh
    - name: 'git'
      path: /root/.gitconfig

  - name: 'golang'
    args: ['make', 'review']
    volumes:
    - name: 'ssh'
      path: /root/.ssh
    - name: 'git'
      path: /root/.gitconfig

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/my-project/secrets/ssh-private-key/versions/latest
    env: 'SSH_KEY'
```

I have also set these go env variables:

```
GOPRIVATE=github.com/myOrg/*
GO111MODULE=on
```

So it seems that the SSH part is working fine, but somehow I cant fetch my private dependencies.

Comment: I guess that the `/root` dir already exist in the current container image and thus you can't override them with volumes. And thus the volume data aren't kept and restore in the subsequent steps. Anyway, if my assumption is the correct one, an error from Cloud Build (or a warning) would have been welcome.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Alright. In the guide I linked, they specified the ’/root/.ssh’ volume. The error I got was the one I added in the post. The other steps exits with 0.